# input post return null when testing on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form sent to ajax, it works fine in localhost, but it gives me error when uploaded to server :
error at line 29 in model/Excel.php. This is the line 29 `$this->db->insert('update',$data_user)`

I cannot find the mistake. Please help..

```html
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

INSERT INTO `request` (`email`, `name`, `phone`, `status`, `filename_user`) VALUES ([email protected]', 'tes email', '436354', '0', '5760c25d7fa87.xlsx')

Filename: models/Excel.php

Line Number: 29
```

Excel models :

```html
function tambahuser($data_user)
{
  $this->db->insert('request', $data_user);
  $this->db->insert_id();
            
  foreach ($data_user as $key)     
  {  
   $data = array(
     'email'  =>   $this->input->post('email'),
     'from_name'  =>   $this->input->post('from_nama'),
     'from_phone' =>   $this->input->post('from_phone')
   );
  }
}
```

The controller :

```html
function undangan()
 {
  $this->load->library('session');
   $email          =   $this->input->post('email');
   $from_nama  =   $this->input->post('from_nama');
   $from_phone  =   $this->input->post('from_phone');

   $data_user = array(

    'email' => $email,
    'name'  => $from_nama,
    'phone' => $from_phone,
    'status'=> '0',
    'filename_user' => $this->session->xls, //upload filename
       );

            $this->load->model('excel');
            
   $this->excel->tambahuser($data_user);
            $this->load->library('email_ses');
            $this->email_ses->send();
            
         
  echo json_encode(array("email" => $email, "from_nama" => $from_nama,"from_phone" => $from_phone ));
 } 
}
```

The form :

```html
<h4 id="form">Data Personal</h4>
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="email"  name="email"  placeholder="Email" required>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  id="from_nama" name="from_nama" placeholder="Nama" required>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
   <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg"  id="from_phone"  name="from_phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
</div>
                            
<div class="row" id="button_pesan" align="center" style="display: none;">
  <button id="pesan" type="button" class="btn btn-download btn-md" onclick=pesan()>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true" ></span>Pesan
  </button>
</div>
```

Ajax function :

```js
function pesan()
    { 
        email = $("#email").val(); 
        from_nama = $("#from_nama").val(); 
        from_phone = $("#from_phone").val(); 

        $.ajax
        ({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('kirim/undangan')?>/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data:{from_nama: from_nama, email: email, from_phone: from_phone},
            success: function(data)
            {       
               $('#alert_sukses').show();
               $('#form_pesan').hide();
               $('#myModalLabel').hide();
               
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error upload data');
            }

        });
    }
```

Table `request` structure :

[image]

Comment: There is problem with Database. The `'status'` field in *request* table is PRIMARY key. So the two statuses with 0 value can not be inserted. Change parameter of *status* field.

Comment: yes, the `status` field is not primary key, the primary key is `request_id`

Comment: what is the `request_id` used for? If it's a primary key maybe you should have it `auto_increment`? Depending on what your problem is that may just be a patch :/. Can you post your database schema?

Comment: just an aside but is there a purpose for the foreach in the tambahuser($data_user) method in the model? you might want to get rid of it if its not doing anything useful.

Comment: i have edited my post , adding a table structure @ksealey

Comment: I directly `db->insert` after array `$datauser` without sending it to model, but it gives me the same error. Anyway, you're right about unnecessary `foreach`. Thank you @cartalot

Comment: is there something wrong with my ajax function?. Thing that makes me confuse is why it works fine on localhost but not in the server? :( @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev

Comment: Please remove previously stored data & try again. I think, there are rows where you have stored same data in primary key field.